# Create toolbar with expanded searchview and additional icon

Tags: android, toolbar, searchview

EDIT:
I'm trying to implement a toolbar with an expanded `searchview` and an edit icon next to the `search view`, it the end it should look like this:

[image]

If I click on the `search view`, I want to stay on the same screen though and show the search results below the searchview like this:

[image]

Redmans commment helped me to show the `searchview`always by setting it to `setIconifiedByDefault(false)` to expand it, but this hides the edit icon. Setting both items to `app:showAsAction="always"` and giving them an order with `android:orderInCategory` and a value of 1 for edit icon will show it, but in the wrong order:

[image]

How can I get this result in the first picture with the edit button on the right side next to the `searchview`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your xml of search view

```
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
```

this will expand the search view automatically

Comment: Do you mean this should be added in the searchable configuration or in the xml of the menu used for the toolbar to add the searchview? Both options don't change anything for me unfortunately. I just tried, setting this option programmatically also doesn't work.

Comment: Forgot to change the showAction to always. Now this comes very close to want I want to do, but it hides the other items I have in my toolbar, what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: try decreasing the width of search view

Comment: Doesn't work, the size doesn't change, no matter which value I set, e.g.          `searchView.setMaxWidth(200);`

Comment: My mistake, I have set the width at another place, afterwards this worked fine, thanks!